# What can possibly turn litmus paper white if there is even no chlorine present?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I did a hydrocarbon test on cyclohexane with bromine solution. The mixture was put inside a dark place. To be exact, a cupboard filled with laboratory equipments. I also put a piece of wet blue litmus paper on top of the tube.
It should've stays blue because there was no reaction occured, right? But the litmus paper turned white. What can possibly cause it?

Comment: Perhaps, bromine also has bleaching capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chlorine turns litmus paper white by oxidizing it.  There are, of course, other oxidizing agents (like bromine) that can do the same thing; chlorine is just the best known because we associate it with commercial bleaches.